# Edit adminstration GUI of weceem

Tags: user-interface, grails, administration, weceem

I am using GGTS 3.6.3.SR1 with grails 2.4.4 and installed the weceem plugin version 1.3. 
Is it somehow possible to edit the admin GUI of weceem? When you are logged in the administration panel and have chosen a space you have a nav-menu where is written "+Add Content" "Further Actions" etc.. 
I want to add there another menu item and link it with my own custom gsp which would be only accessible through the admin panel but not for normal visitors.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add link to your own controller/action/JSP as the one more menu-link on administration tab 
(there you should see menu with links for 'Spaces', 'Synchronize','license', etc.).
For that aim, in your application you can create/update YourAppNavigation.groovy file (in folder 'grails-app/config/'). 
Then in this file you can specify where you want to see the new editor/link/etc.

For example, in Weceem demo application there is the following navigation:

```
navigation = {
    weceem_admin {
        misc(controller:'foo', action:'index', order:5)

    }
}
```

Please, check http://jcatalog.github.io/weceem-plugin/guide/customization.html#0.HookingIntoTheAdminInterface for more details. 
Any link can be restricted using WeceemSecurityPolicy, check http://jcatalog.github.io/weceem-plugin/guide/5.WeceemSecuritPolicy.html

Comment: Yeah, this works, but it seems to be only possible to customize this specific menu.